# Building a Reporting Services Report for CRM Online 2013

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, fetchxml

I've installed

- Visual Studio 2012
- SQL Server 2012 with Reporting services.
- Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2013 Report Authoring Extension (with SQL Server Data Tools support).

When I attempt to add a datasource to my project, I dont see anything related to FetchXml or CRM Online.

Is there anything else i need in order to build a reporting services report that uses FetchXml  to pull down data from CRM Online 2013?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know you will have to use VS2010 (BIDS) to develop reports for CRM 2013.

Comment: this is supported by the system requirements on the download page for the authoring extension (http://www.microsoft.com/en-nz/download/details.aspx?id=40343) - "Business Intelligence Development Studio and Visual Studio 2008 Service Pack 1
-OR- 
SQL Server Data Tools and Visual Studio 2010"